# Create a new app pool and assign it to a site subfolder on a remote host, using C# and IIS7

Tags: c#, iis-7, application-pool

I have a web site running on IIS7 on a remote server. I would like to do the following:

1. Create a new subfolder under the root virtual directory.
2. Create a new app pool.
3. Add this new app pool to the new subfolder

Normally, I would do this manually in IIS by first creating the app pool, and then right-clicking the sub folder an choose "add application", but I need to do this programmatically in C#. I've managed to make the above points 1 and 2 work, but I can't find the way to adding the application to the sub folder.

This is the code I have used so far for 1 and 2:

```
ServerManager mgr = new ServerManager();
    ApplicationPool myAppPool = mgr.ApplicationPools.Add("MyAppPool");
    myAppPool.AutoStart = true;
    myAppPool.Cpu.Action = ProcessorAction.KillW3wp;
    myAppPool.ManagedPipelineMode = ManagedPipelineMode.Integrated;
    myAppPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion = "V4.0";
    myAppPool.ProcessModel.IdentityType = ProcessModelIdentityType.NetworkService;
    mgr.CommitChanges();


    if (!Directory.Exists(@"D:\webroot\TestSite\NytSite"))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\webroot\TestSite\NytSite");
    }
```

So, I need to add "MyAppPool" to the "NytSite" folder...

Is this even the correct way to do this?

Any experiences out there?

Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new Application to assign an application pool, so you can do this:

```
        if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\JohnSite"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\JohnSite");
        }

        // Add to my default site
        var app = mgr.Sites[0].Applications.Add(@"/JohnSite", @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\JohnSite");
        app.ApplicationPoolName = "MyAppPool";

        mgr.CommitChanges();
```